# What protocol is Window's v6v4tunnel implementing?

Tags: windows-7, ipv6, tunnel, teredo, 6to4

Microsoft Windows allows the creation of an "*IPv6-in-IPv4 point-to-point tunnel*":

```
>netsh interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel "My Tunnel" 192.168.1.13 209.51.181.2
```

My question is: what protocol is this?

i know `netsh` exposes access to other tunneling or IPv6 transition protocols:

- `6to4`: [RFC3056 - Connection of IPv6 Domains via IPv4 Clouds](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3056.txt)
- `isatap`: [RFC5214 - Intra-Site Automatic Tunnel Addressing Protocol (ISATAP)](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5214.txt)
- `teredo`: [RFC4380 - Teredo: Tunneling IPv6 over UDP through Network Address Translations (NATs)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4380.txt)
- `v6v4tunnel`: ?
- `httpstunnel`: ?
- `portproxy`: ?

What protocol is `v6v4tunnel` implementing?

The reason i ask is because there's no documentation from Microsoft; so reading an RFC will have to be my documentation.

### See also

- [Technet: IPv6 Transition Technologies (TechRef)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379548%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v6v4tunnel` is a simple [6in4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6in4) tunnel, using IPv6 in IPv4 proto-41 packets as defined in [RFC 4213](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4213#section-3.1) ("host-to-router"). Sometimes this is called a "Protocol 41" tunnel.

This tunnel type is used by [Tunnelbroker](http://tunnelbroker.com/) and other IPv6 tunnel providers. The Linux equivalent is a *`sit`* tunnel interface.

---

`portproxy` is a transport-layer proxy that listens for TCP connections and relays them to the configured destinations, similar to how [6tunnel](http://toxygen.net/6tunnel/) works on Linux.