# How to setup pfSense 2.0 for TunnelBroker.net?

Tags: ipv6, tunnel, gif, pfsense

What is the procedure to create an IPv6 tunnel in pfSense 2.0?

---

pfSense 2.0 (RC3) supports creation of a GIF tunnels:

[image]

[The help](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/GIF_Interfaces) is pretty generic, and pretty unhelpful:

> In pfSense 2.0, GIF tunneling interfaces are added from Interfaces (assign) on the GIF tab.
>
> GIF is a generic tunneling mechanism that can be used for IPv4 and IPv6 traffic.
>
> GIF tunnels can be [added, edited, or deleted](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Managing_Lists_of_Items_on_pfSense) from the list view.
>
> When adding or editing a GIF interface, you must enter its interface,
>   remote address, and local and remote tunnel addresses. You can
>   optionally enable Route caching, ECN friendly behavior, and a
>   description.
>
> Be aware, with GIF interfaces and bridging, you cannot
>   ping the router endpoints, but clients can still ping each other.
>   Without bridging, you should still be able to reach the router
>   endpoint IPs with ping.

When [created a tunnel from TunnelBroker.net on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/314546/what-protocol-is-windows-v6v4tunnel-implementing) there were only 3 important pieces of information:

- Tunnel Entry-Point Node: **192.168.1.98**
- Tunnel Exit-Point Node: **209.51.181.2**
- Client IPv6 Address: **2001:470:1f11:1178::2/64**

and then then tunnel needs a default gateway IPv6 address:

- Server IPv6 Address: **2001:470:1f11:1178::1/64**

[image]

So on Windows you create the tunnel using:

```
netsh interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel IP6Tunnel 192.168.1.98 209.51.181.2
netsh interface ipv6 add address IP6Tunnel 2001:470:1f11:1178::2
netsh interface ipv6 add route ::/0 IP6Tunnel 2001:470:1f11:1178::1
```

Now in this case i set the tunnel entrance IPv4 address to my desktop machine's internal **LAN address** (e.g. 192.168.1.98), rather than my router's WAN address. This is because the tunnel entrance *is* on my local machine.

Now it comes to creating a tunnel on pfSense.

- **Parent interface**: `LAN`|`WAN`
- **gif remote address**:
- **gif tunnel local address**:
- **gif tunnel remote address**:

i don't know the difference between:

- gif remote address
- gif tunnel remote address

and i don't know if **gif tunnel local address** should be:

- the router's IPv4 LAN address (e.g. 192.168.1.1) on the LAN interface
- the router's IPv4 WAN (*current*) address (e.g. 216.8.139.7) on the WAN interface

i randomly tried the following, but it does nothing (at all):

[image]

---

TunnelBroker.net includes some scripts for FreeBSD to create and configure the tunnel:

```
ifconfig gif0 create
ifconfig gif0 tunnel 216.8.139.7 209.51.181.2
ifconfig gif0 inet6 2001:470:1f11:1178::2 2001:470:1f10:1178::1 prefixlen 128
route -n add -inet6 default 2001:470:1f11:1178::1
ifconfig gif0 up
```

My question ended after the first line. The only reason i included another 3 screenfuls of information is that [some people get pissy when you only ask a question](https://superuser.com/questions/313265/ssl-vpn-client). Also by posting a lot of meaningless junk it shows that i actually tried - which some people find important.

---

**Edit**: There is a three year old post on the pfSense forums ([IPv6 behind pfsense.](http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php/topic,9664.0.html)) that talks about manually adding IPv6 tunnel support to pfSense 1. i'm looking for expanded documentation/explanation/tutorial for use with pfSense 2.0 UI.

### See also

- [IPv6 behind pfsense.](http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php/topic,9664.msg54668.html#msg54668)
- [pfSense documentation: GIF Interfaces](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/GIF_Interfaces)
- [Experimental IPv6 support if pfSense 2.0 BETA](http://iserv.nl/files/pfsense/ipv6/)
- [TunnelBroker.net Forums: [Announce] Prelimenary IPv6 Support in pfSense](http://www.tunnelbroker.net/forums/index.php?topic=1251.0)
- [pfSense Foruma: GIF tunnel on PPPoE reconnect / HE.net tunnelbroker IP DynDNS](http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php/topic,38296.0.html)
- [GIF tunnel on PPPoE reconnect / HE.net tunnelbroker IP DynDNS](http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php/topic,38296.0.html)